# TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable error in Python 3

Tags: python, nltk, typeerror

I am trying to use the FreqDist that is part of NLTK in Python.
I tried this sample code:

```
fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)
vocabulary1 = fdist1.keys()
vocabulary1[:50]
```

but the last line gives me this error:

```
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

I think the code runs fine on Python 2, but on Python 3 (that I have) it give the above error.

Why is this error and how to resolve it? I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Add `list()` around the call to fdist1.keys()

Comment: Ha ha, like OP, I too got stumped here when I was going through Oreilly's text book on NLTK! Guess I must accustom myself to Python 3 now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3 `.keys()` returns an iterator, which you can't slice. Convert it to a list before slicing.

```
fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)
vocabulary1 = fdist1.keys()
x = list(vocabulary1)[:50]
# or...
vocabulary1 = list(fdist1.keys())
x = vocabulary1[:50]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to list first:

```
new_vocab= list(vocabulary1)
...= new_vocab[:50]
```